# geom_rect does not respect x and y limits in for loop

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, limit

I am trying to use `geom_rect` in a `for` loop, but it does not respect my limits. It does if I call it outside of the context of a `for` loop. Is this a bug? Or is there something I don't understand about `geom_rect`? `outPlot_free` and `outPlot1` should be identical (since .2 = .2/1), but the rectangles in `outPlot1` are truncated, and interestingly they are identical to `outPlot2`, `outPlot3` and `outPlot4`.

```r
library('ggplot2')
library('ggrepel')

sum_df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=10, ncol=3))
colnames(sum_df) <- c("Variable", "Male", "Female")
sum_df$Variable <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")

covar = .7*.1*.1
Sigma = matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2,c(.2^2,covar,covar,.2^2))
temp = eigen(Sigma)
SqrtSigma = temp$vectors%*%diag(sqrt(temp$values))%*%t(temp$vectors)
XYvec = c(0,0) + SqrtSigma%*%rnorm(2)

for(i in 1:10){
  XYvec = c(0,0) + SqrtSigma%*%rnorm(2)
  sum_df$Female[i] = XYvec[1]
  sum_df$Male[i] = XYvec[2]
}

outPlot_free <- ggplot(sum_df, aes(x=Male, y=Female)) + theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-.2, xmax=.2, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="grey97", color=NA, alpha=.5, size=0) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin=-.2, ymax=.2, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf), fill="grey97", color=NA, alpha=.5, size=0) +
  geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label=Variable)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1, 1), breaks=round(seq(-1, 1, .1), digits=2)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1, 1), breaks=round(seq(-1, 1, .1), digits=2)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, linetype="dotdash", alpha=.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grey60", "black")) + xlab("Female") + ylab("Male") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") + geom_vline(xintercept=.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=-.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") + geom_vline(xintercept=-.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") 

for (q in 1:4) {
  covar = .7*.1*.1
  Sigma = matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2,c(.2^2,covar,covar,.2^2))
  temp = eigen(Sigma)
  SqrtSigma = temp$vectors%*%diag(sqrt(temp$values))%*%t(temp$vectors)
  XYvec = c(0,0) + SqrtSigma%*%rnorm(2)

  for(i in 1:10){
    XYvec = c(0,0) + SqrtSigma%*%rnorm(2)
    sum_df$Female[i] = XYvec[1]
    sum_df$Male[i] = XYvec[2]
  }


  outPlot <- ggplot(sum_df, aes(x=Male, y=Female)) + theme_minimal() + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=-.2/q, xmax=.2/q, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="grey97", color=NA, alpha=.5, size=0) +
    geom_rect(aes(ymin=-.2/q, ymax=.2/q, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf), fill="grey97", color=NA, alpha=.5, size=0) +
    geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label=Variable)) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1, 1), breaks=round(seq(-1, 1, .1), digits=2)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1, 1), breaks=round(seq(-1, 1, .1), digits=2)) +
    geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, linetype="dotdash", alpha=.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("grey60", "black")) + xlab("Female") + ylab("Male") +
    geom_hline(yintercept=.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") + geom_vline(xintercept=.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") +
    geom_hline(yintercept=-.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") + geom_vline(xintercept=-.2, linetype="dashed", color="slateblue") 

  assign(paste0("outPlot", q), outPlot)
}

outPlot_free
```

[image]

```r
outPlot1
```

[image]

```r
outPlot2
```

[image]

```r
outPlot3
```

[image]

```r
outPlot4
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`outPlot_free` and `outPlot1` should be identical except for the plotted points, since they were independently simulated.

Comment: *outPlot_free and outPlot1 should be identical except for the plotted points, since they were independently simulated

Comment: well, it would be easier if you would have provided a minimal example whcih focusses on the non working parts only. Anyway, which limits do you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is lazy evaluation in R. It's a common problem when writing code containing loops, in particular if you're approaching the language from a procedural mindset. For more details, see e.g. here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

In the following example, the first is what you're doing (in effect), and the second is what you should be doing.

```r
# doesn't work as expected, as the variable i in the function call
# is evaluated only after the loop is run
x <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  x[[i]] <- function() {i}
}
x[[1]]()
#> [1] 3
x[[2]]()
#> [1] 3
x[[3]]()
#> [1] 3

# by writing a function generator, we can bind the variable i
# to the specific function we're generating in each iteration
# of the loop
x <- list()
f_generator <- function(i) {
  force(i)
  function() {i}
}
for (i in 1:3) {
  x[[i]] <- f_generator(i)
}
x[[1]]()
#> [1] 1
x[[2]]()
#> [1] 2
x[[3]]()
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In the context of your code, write a function that generates the plot, call `force()` on all the arguments to that function, and then inside the `for()` loop call that function to create the specific plot objects you need. See the following example.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# this doesn't work, the line in the first plot should be placed
# at y = 1 but is placed at y = 2
plots <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  data <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1))
  plots[[i]] <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y = i)) + geom_line() + ylim(0, 3)
}

plot_grid(plotlist = plots, labels = c(1:2))
```

[image]

```r
# this does work
plots <- list()
plot_fun <- function(i) {
  force(i)
  data <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1))
  ggplot(data, aes(x, y = i)) + geom_line() + ylim(0, 3)
}
for (i in 1:2) {
  plots[[i]] <- plot_fun(i)
}

plot_grid(plotlist = plots, labels = c(1:2))
```

[image]

And finally, once you have written a function that generates your plots, the idiomatic approach in R would be to not write a `for` loop but instead use `lapply()` or `map()`. It turns out that if you get used to using these functions instead of `for` loops you're much less likely to run into the problem you're experiencing, because R is not a procedural language.

```r
# this replaces the for loop
plots <- lapply(1:2, plot_fun)

plot_grid(plotlist = plots, labels = c(1:2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>